# How to get data of the current time from mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have data per day in my database mysql.  What I want to do is to select the km field in the current time in the day minus the km field in start of the day (current day time :00:00 am). 
I tried this but it didnt work:

```
SELECT km from position where serverTime=startOfTheDay

SELECT km from position where serverTime=currentTime()
```

These two requests don't work.  I just need an idea of what I need to do.
Also, I need to minus the last km from the first one, help please??

[image]

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Not sure what you want. but to get the current time you use [CURRENT_TIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: thank for answer,,i'm sorry i didnt know how to put the question..i think its improved

Comment: look what i want is to get the km in the start of the day and the km of the cuurrent time

Comment: then substruct them

Comment: As I say, show us sample data and expected output.

Comment: How is serverTime defined? current_time() is down to the second - your query may come up blank... And yes, you can perform 'math' like subtractions on dates/times - google is your friend.

Comment: Assuming that kms are increasing it's something like `select max(km) - min(km) from position where ServerTime > cast(current_date as timestamp)`

Comment: dnoeth i think you near of the answer but how i can get the start time of the day..??

Comment: `current_date` give you only the date then `cast(current_date as timestamp)` will give you date with 00:00:00 so everything from the start of the day until now. `MIN()` will be the first km of the day, `Max()` will be the last km of the day.

Comment: can you put your answer as a valid answer please

Comment: btw you table km only show value `7` and `41` one of the requirement for dnoeth solution is the km be incremental overtime

Comment: can you put the table as text ? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach - it finds the difference between the smallest and largest km for each day.

```
select min(serverTime) as start, 
       max(serverTime) as stop, 
       max(km) - min(km) as km_difference
from position
group by date(serverTime);
```

Comment: curdate will give oly the date i need the start of the date and time

Comment: I edited the query - you will see start and stop timestamp as well as km difference for each day.  If you care about a day in particular, you can filter with a where clause (preferable) or in a having.

Comment: The original query was finding the KM difference for the current day - which seemed to be what you were asking for.

Comment: To get the current day only use `where ServerTime >= cast(current_date as timestamp)`

Answer (score 0):

First one (and only works if you have properly defined the col serverTime): `SELECT... curdate()`

Comment: thinks the requests above do not work i want just give a rough idea

Comment: As others are implying, without giving us more detail on your tables and data, your 'rough idea' could be a waste of time. If you want help, supply a little info.

Comment: i've just added the table above